# How do I print cents as decimals?

Tags: python

This is what I've done already but how do I print cents as decimals?

```
print("Bank account balance: 2000 €")
euros = float(input("How many euros will be added to the balance?" ))
cents = float(input("How many cents will be added to the balance?" ))
sum = 2000 + euros + cents
print("Bank account balance:", sum)
```

Comment: divide cents by 100?

Comment: I would also be careful with allowing the whole euros to be a float value. The floating point will be the number of cents, however there can be a fraction of a cent allowed which might introduce errors.

Comment: In addition to following @AKX 's advice, format the resulting number to have 2 decimal places on output: `print(f"Bank account balance: {sum:.2f}")`.

Answer (score 1):

Divide `cents` by 100 (as you would in any math ("kuinka monta senttiä on yksi euro?")).

```
sum = 2000 + euros + cents / 100
```